# I have an error in the climate of gnome manjaro extension, can someone help me?

Tags: shell, gnome, manjaro

hi i got this bug in gnome weather and i cant get it to work

The settings of extension weather-extension@xeked.com had an error:

```
TypeError: GWeather.Location.new_world is not a function
```

Stack trace:

```
@/home/mrmateo/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/weather-extension@xeked.com/prefs.js:100:28
_init@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:204:33
OpenExtensionPrefsAsync/<@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:122:28
asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:115:22
run@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/dbusService.js:177:20
main@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/main.js:19:13
run@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:206:19
start@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:190:8
@/usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Extensions:1:17
```